# Jquery Scroll Animation not Working on Mobile?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to show an Header on a Website after scrolling. My problem is that it works perfect on desktop but it didn't work on any mobile device(browser).
This is the code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $ (window).scrollTop() >= 500) {
            $ ('#site_header').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $ ('#site_header').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: Make a reproducible example, or at least add html.

Comment: A little bit difficult because its wordpress :)

Comment: Is the project local or hosted?

Comment: The project is hosted on an AWS Server but without HTTPS could this be a problem

Comment: Clear caches, and see if your code is loading in your dom because the code looks good and it should work, when I try your code for StackOverflow site with just replacing `#site_header` with their header `.top-bar`, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think This will happen if you're using the "slim" version of jQuery. Only the "full" version of jQuery includes animation effects.

Try grabbing the "full" version of jQuery from the [jQuery downloads page](https://jquery.com/download/) and including that in your page (or including a full version of [jQuery from a CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) from your page).